# Can't apply css to the form

Tags: html, css

i am currently working on `css`. i have a sample form and a css but it is not working
its only working with the labels but there is no change in the design part i am beginner in `CSS` so i am not sure what is the issue here

the html code :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post" class="STYLE-NAME">
<h1>Contact Form 
    <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
</h1>
<label>
    <span>Your Name :</span>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
</label>
<p>
<label>
    <span>Your Email :</span>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
</label>
<p>
<label>
    <span>Message :</span>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message to Us"></textarea>
</label>
  <p>  
 <label>
    <span>Subject :</span><select name="selection">
    <option value="Job Inquiry">Job Inquiry</option>
    <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
    </select>
</label>
   <p>   
 <label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Send" /> 
</label>    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

i have linked this code with an external style sheet which i downloaded from net just for practice but its not working

CSS file :

```
.basic-grey {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
max-width: 500px;
background: #F7F7F7;
padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: #888;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.basic-grey h1 {
font-size: 25px;
padding: 0px 0px 10px 40px;
display: block;
border-bottom:1px solid #E4E4E4;
margin: -10px -15px 30px -10px;;
color: #888;
}
.basic-grey h1>span {
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
}
.basic-grey label {
display: block;
margin: 0px;
}
.basic-grey label>span {
float: left;
width: 20%;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
color: #888;
}
.basic-grey input[type="text"], .basic-grey input[type="email"],.basic-grey textarea,       

.basic-grey select {
border: 1px solid #DADADA;
color: #888;
height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 16px;
margin-right: 6px;
margin-top: 2px;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
width: 70%;
font-size: 12px;
line-height:15px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
padding: 5px 3px 3px 5px;
}
.basic-grey select {
background: #FFF url(arrowhead.png) no-repeat right;
background: #FFF url(arrowhead.png) no-repeat right;
appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none; 
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
width: 70%;
height: 35px;
line-height: 25px;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
height:100px;
}
.basic-grey .button {
background: #E27575;
border: none;
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #B6B6B6;
border-radius: 3px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9E3F3F;
cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-grey .button:hover {
background: #CF7A7A
}
```

Comment: Try to specify the style name `<form action="" method="post" class="basic-grey">`

Comment: thanks all ... this was a real bad miss its working now

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace `STYLE-NAME` with `basic-grey` in the HTML. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PM8Hr/).

The CSS uses the selector `.basic-grey`, which means “elements whose `class` attribute contains at least `basic-grey`”. You don’t have any attribute with this class in your HTML. You thus need to either change the CSS’ selectors to something like `form`, or add the class on the HTML elements. In this case, adding the `basic-grey` class to the form fixes the whole thing.

Comment: my bad ..its fine now

Answer (score 0):

None of your items in the HTML have a class `.basic-X`.

For the CSS to work you need to do this or change the HTML/CSS.

Please re-read the chapter on selectors

Answer (score 0):

For a start you have unbalanced `<p>` tags, i.e.

```
<p>  
  <label>
    <span>Subject :</span>
      <select name="selection">
        <option value="Job Inquiry">Job Inquiry</option>
        <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
      </select>
  </label>
<!-- this last one should be a closing tag </p> -->
<p>
```

Secondly, you have

```
<form action="" method="post" class="STYLE-NAME">
```

Are you sure STYLE-NAME resolves to what you want it to be? Perhaps your template engine is spitting something else out?

Comment: Unbalanced `<p>` tags are valid if the `p` element is immediately followed by another `p` element or if there’s no more content in the parent element, which is the case here ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-tags)).